# Xamarin Forms Map Android CustomRenderer MoveToRegion Not Working After Upgrading To API25

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I've just upgraded my application to Android 7.1(API25) and update NuGet Packages as decribed below:

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServive.Maps to v42.1021.1
Xamarin.Forms to v2.3.4.247
Xamarin.Forms.Maps to v2.3.4.247
Xamarin.Android.Support.V4 to v25.3.1
Xamarin.Android.Support.V7.* to v25.3.1
```

I'm benefiting from a CustomMap class derived from Map class and an android CustomRenderer. Everything was working well before, but after update, the method MoveToRegion() doesn't do anything and even map doesn't initialize at the initial MapSpan I passed to ctor.

I can't find out the reason.
Please give me any possible cause. I'll try anything to solve this FORCE MAJOR Issue!

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample project demonstrating the problem?

Comment: isn't this a known bug, I think theres a bugzilla report for it, in the commentary theres a link to a temp patch. If I get time I'll try and find it.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Did you find something? I didn't.

Comment: @Hosein  Yes sorry, this is the link to the bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52625   and the plugin that you can get from Nuget is called Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.TemporaryPatch   - worth a look to see if it matches your issue.

Comment: @Digitalsa1nt Thanks but it wasn't my issue. I had this problem and disabled linking and it was solved for now. Also the nuget is unlisted by it's owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hack to overcome this issue for now.
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/264930/#Comment_264930

It appears that the base class of my CustomMapRenderer class(Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer) has a method for implementing IOnMapReadyCallback named OnMapReady which doesn't get called. All I had to do was implementing IOnMapReadyCallback and add a method OnMapReady that calls InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(Calling base class OnMapReady):

```
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    ...

    InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(googleMap);
}

private void InvokeOnMapReadyBaseClassHack(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo onMapReadyMethodInfo = null;

    Type baseType = typeof(MapRenderer);
    foreach (var currentMethod in baseType.GetMethods(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
                                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
    {

        if (currentMethod.IsFinal && currentMethod.IsPrivate)
        {
            if (string.Equals(currentMethod.Name, "OnMapReady", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                onMapReadyMethodInfo = currentMethod;

                break;
            }

            if (currentMethod.Name.EndsWith(".OnMapReady", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            {
                onMapReadyMethodInfo = currentMethod;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (onMapReadyMethodInfo != null)
    {
        onMapReadyMethodInfo.Invoke(this, new[] { googleMap });
    }
}
```